# How / can you make subclips from sequences in Adobe Premiere CC?

Tags: premiere, editing, adobe, clipping

Subclips are great for organizing. This makes a lot of sense when you either do it in prelude ahead of time etc. But what about when you want to make clips from say an interview.

I have a sequence for each interview, each sequence has a video clip, audio track, and adjustment layer for effects. I want to now be able to create subclips of this as if it were a single video clip. (Yes I know I could export it as a video clip and then make clips but the point is I want to have a bunch of clips that are linked to the sequence so that way if I go back and make changes to the audio or the adjustment layer it will effect all the clips.)

I know you can right click on the sequence and "Open in Source Monitor" and create clips that way, however I noticed when you then make changes to the original sequence they do not update the clips. I.E. the clips are separate pieces and not linked.

Is there a way to create linked subclips from sequences in premiere pro CC?

—-
Note:
Though there are workarounds with nested sequences there really isn’t a feature like this in Premiere. To me it seems like with professional editing this should be something that’s used way more often, or maybe there is a different methodology for how to edit those. I think this would be a really useful feature

Answer (score 1):

If you convert all the clips in your timeline (video, audio, adjustment layer) into a Compound Clip, then underlying changes will be properly reflected in your Compound Clip.

Comment: Right, that’s just nesting sequences. So what you can do is make the whole sequence a nested clip and then cut it up into the clips you want. But then you still have to reference the sequence you made those edits in to grab those pieces. You can’t like, have each of those pieces be in the media browser and previewable, renamed, add metadata etc.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** *This isn't the answer that OP was looking for but I'll leave it here for now in case it is of help to anyone else looking to do something similar. Sorry OP!*

Try selecting the necessary items on the timeline, right click and select 'Make Subsequence' - this will create a brand new sequence out of those items and leave them where they are (R-click & 'Nest' will REPLACE those items with the nested sequence). You can then drag and drop the subsequence onto a timeline in another sequence and, when you double-click to open the subsequence, any changes you make in there will be reflected in the parent timeline.

You can also just create a brand new sequence and drag any other sequence into it, then amend the original sequences to have those changes reflected in the parent.

Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer:

[image: Subsequence Creation & Editing]

As I said above, you can use 'Make Subsequence' instead of 'Nest' to create a new sequence but NOT replace the footage in the timeline, or skip this step and create a new MASTER sequence and drop existing sequences into it.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the answer. If you look at the comment I left on Michaels post it’s kind of the same idea. You can make subsequences and best sequences but only one. As in, if you make a nest sequence and cut it up then you can have clips. You can make multiple nested sequences becuase then it’s sub components don’t all get edited the same. That being said, neither of those solutions are previewable in the project panel as clips. There would only be one nested sequence clip, or a single sequence that contains all the cut up clip items.

Comment: Right - I think I get you now! You'd like to be able to set in-out points in a timeline and create dependent clips from that original timeline that you can drop into different (sequences/projects?) and still be able to go back into the main project and make changes that are reflected in those dependants. Unfortunately, you've hit the nail on the head in that Premiere doesn't have that function. Creating subsequences preserves the original sequence by design so changes there won't be reflected in subsequences derived from that sequence. I apologise for my earlier misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the support. I know it seems like maybe a specific use case but I feel like it could be fairly useful for organizational purposes